# Proving convergence to a certain limit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Suppose that the sequence $(X_n)$ has the following property: there is a real number $a$ such that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $X_n = a$. Prove that, if $X_n$ converges at all, its limit must equal $a$.

So my attempts at solving this question involve using the formal definition of the limit, which is:

> A sequence $(Sn)$ of real numbers is said to converge to the real number $s$ provided that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a number $N$ such that  $n>N$ implies $|S_n - s| < \epsilon$ If $(S_n)$ converges to $s$ we will write $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=s$ or $S_n\to s$.

So I'm not sure where to head exactly besides using this definition. The answer is almost seems to be painstakingly obvious to me, but I can't really get over the hump. My guess is to first prove that is converges, and then apply this limit definition at the end. Any thoughts?

Comment: By assumption, $a$ is an accumulation point of the sequence. A sequence converges if and only if it has only one accumulation point, which must then be $a$.

Comment: if you want to use the formal definition (which is probably the goal of the exercise), then assume it has a limit $s\neq a$, and shows that the definition of limit fails for $\epsilon<|s-a|$.

Answer (score 1):

*Lemma:* A sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if all of its subsequences converge to the same point.

*Proof:* $\Rightarrow$
\begin{align}
(x_n)&\to x\\
\therefore \mbox{Given } \epsilon>0, \exists N \;s.t. \forall n\geq N& |x_n-x|<\epsilon\\
\end{align} 
Now, let $(y_n)$ be any subsequence of $(x_n)$. 
For all $n\geq N$, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$. But this also means that there exists a $N_y$ such that for all $n\geq N_y$, $|y_n-x|<\epsilon$. Thus, $(y_n)\to x$

---

Now, let us define $(y_n)$ to be a sequence consisting of each term of the sequence being $a$. (We can do this because we know there are infinitely many such terms). Thus, $(y_n)$ being a constant sequence, trivially converges to $a$. Now, if $(x_n)$ does converge, it must converge to $a$. Because, if it converged to anything else, it would violate the Lemma above.

Comment: Thanks, the way in which you included a lemma made it much easier to organize and read the response. A proof etiquette I will consider adding to my own repertoire in the future...

Comment: @Iam126264. Thank You! If you feel that my answer appropriately answers your question, you can mark it as accepted (the tick-mark on the left). If it doesn't, no rush :)

Answer (score 0):

**Fisrts method:**
Let $s$ the limit of $(X_n)$, and let $\varepsilon >0$
$$(\exists N \in \Bbb N )(\forall n \geq N) \quad |X_n-s| < \varepsilon$$
By hypothsis there exists  $n \geq N$ such that $X_n=a$, then $|a-s| < \varepsilon$

This shows that : $$\forall \varepsilon >0 \quad |a-s| < \varepsilon$$

that means : $a=s$.

**Second metthod:** The given hypothesis means that there exists  a subsequence of $(X_n)$  who converges to $a$. If $(X_n)$  converges to $s$ all subsequences of $(X_n)$  converges to $s$ then $s=a$.

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate you including both a numerical proof and one that includes a simple worded answer. Although I think the second method would qualify as an alternate backup answer moreso than "the" answer.